# Plain text error reporting in Angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I test my app with Karma, getting the output in the console. Is there any way to change the default Angular error reporting to plain text from the URL format? now I get

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=nxPay&p1=TypeError%3A%20'undefined'%20is%20not%20a%20function%20(evaluating%20'window.getBaseURL()')%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9018%2Fbase%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.js%3F4a3cab52eacd58afa3318f88dc0ffc6561c77172%3A182%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F0363ecedbf628298d67dc30dcd838bfff088a1d2%3A33)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9018%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F0363ecedbf628298d67dc30dcd838bfff088a1d2%3A32

And I really would like to get just a text like

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'window.getBaseURL()'): at `http://localhost/base/src/app/app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use UNMINIFIED angular.js in develop